# Отметки о прочтении

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется необходимость на корпоративном сайте сделать для каждого пользователя напротив списка новостей отметку о прочтении, чтобы в дальнейшем можно было отследить, кто из сотрудников уведомлен о данной новости.
Как лучше реализовать? Делать таблицу соответствия (id новостей и id сотрудников)?
У каждого сотрудника в поле "прочитанные" список id прочитанных новостей с разделителями формировать?
Когда сотрудник загружает новости, чтобы отображалось напротив новости "прочитано" или "не прочитано".
Какой способ будет быстрее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы однозначно делал по первому варианту. Отдельная таблица, поле news_id и поле user_id сделать под одним уникальным ключом, а записи добавлять с использованием "INSERT IGNORE ...". Каких-то дополнительных полей и не нужно, дублирование исключено, удобно для дальнейшего использования.